# How to manage caps/alerting metrics in real time?

Tags: php, database, architecture, bigdata

I'm working on an ad campaign management app. There's a feature there advertisers can assign caps for campaign based on spending or conversions in daily, monthly or lifetime basis and there would be multiple caps per ad campaign. As soon as one campaign reaches the 80% we will send notification to all publishes and once caps are reached we have to stop the campaign immediately. We're receiving thousands of event per second. Currently what i'm doing is querying reporting table every second but it's quite inefficient and sometimes campaigns already exceeded the caps when I detect it. So my question is;

1. What're the existing efficient programmatic or architectural solution's in industry to handle these kind of situations?

Comment: You could maybe use a database trigger ("on insert") which checks the 80% limit and then immediately close this campaign (set a flag) directly on database level. Your application can then query the reporting table less often, send the notifications and do other work.